# My Older Heroku App is crashing - Unclear why

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, heroku, crash

I recently updated an older 'Yelp Camp' Heroku app of mine from version 16 to 22. My hope was that this would allow the site to deploy and work correctly. Unfortunately it is continuing to crash on the landing page pretty consistently, and will not load any pages beyond that.

As stated its a very older app that I'm attempting to relearn how I coded. My concern is maybe that some of the languages have updated. I've attached my Heroku logs in the hopes that this can provide clarity as to where I should look, and would appreciate that guidance.

```js
2022-06-19T14:20:22.626158+00:00 app[web.1]: at Pool.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:336:35)
2022-06-19T14:20:22.626158+00:00 app[web.1]: at Pool.emit (node:events:527:28)
2022-06-19T14:20:22.626159+00:00 app[web.1]: at Connection.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:280:12)
2022-06-19T14:20:22.626159+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:642:26)
2022-06-19T14:20:22.626159+00:00 app[web.1]: at Connection.emit (node:events:527:28)
2022-06-19T14:20:22.626160+00:00 app[web.1]: at Socket.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:199:10)
2022-06-19T14:20:22.626160+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:641:28)
2022-06-19T14:20:22.626160+00:00 app[web.1]: at Socket.emit (node:events:527:28)
2022-06-19T14:20:22.626160+00:00 app[web.1]: at Socket._onTimeout (node:net:516:8)
2022-06-19T14:20:22.626161+00:00 app[web.1]: at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:559:17)
2022-06-19T14:20:22.626161+00:00 app[web.1]: at processTimers (node:internal/timers:502:7)
2022-06-19T14:20:22.626161+00:00 app[web.1]: Emitted 'error' event on NativeConnection instance at:
2022-06-19T14:20:22.626162+00:00 app[web.1]: at Immediate.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:325:19)
2022-06-19T14:20:22.626162+00:00 app[web.1]: at processImmediate (node:internal/timers:466:21)
2022-06-19T14:20:22.758152+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2022-06-19T14:20:22.831282+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2022-06-19T15:49:06.900609+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2022-06-19T15:49:08.915023+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2022-06-19T15:49:11.496767+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2022-06-19T15:49:11.496780+00:00 app[web.1]: > v2@1.0.0 start
2022-06-19T15:49:11.496780+00:00 app[web.1]: > node app.js
2022-06-19T15:49:11.496780+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2022-06-19T15:49:11.900063+00:00 app[web.1]: Warning: connect.session() MemoryStore is not
2022-06-19T15:49:11.900080+00:00 app[web.1]: designed for a production environment, as it will leak
2022-06-19T15:49:11.900080+00:00 app[web.1]: memory, and will not scale past a single process.
2022-06-19T15:49:11.905062+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:22) DeprecationWarning: `open()` is deprecated in mongoose >= 4.11.0, use `openUri()` instead, or set the `useMongoClient` option if using `connect()` or `createConnection()`. See http://mongoosejs.com/docs/4.x/docs/connections.html#use-mongo-client
2022-06-19T15:49:11.905063+00:00 app[web.1]: (Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
2022-06-19T15:49:11.905064+00:00 app[web.1]: Yelp camp is running
2022-06-19T15:49:12.083512+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2022-06-19T15:49:41.913180+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2022-06-19T15:49:41.913193+00:00 app[web.1]: node:events:505
2022-06-19T15:49:41.913194+00:00 app[web.1]: throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
2022-06-19T15:49:41.913194+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2022-06-19T15:49:41.913963+00:00 app[web.1]: Error [MongoError]: failed to connect to server [ds249605.mlab.com:49605] on first connect [Error [MongoError]: connection 0 to ds249605.mlab.com:49605 timed out
2022-06-19T15:49:41.913965+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.MongoError.create (/app/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/error.js:29:11)
2022-06-19T15:49:41.913965+00:00 app[web.1]: at Socket.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:200:20)
2022-06-19T15:49:41.913966+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:641:28)
2022-06-19T15:49:41.913966+00:00 app[web.1]: at Socket.emit (node:events:527:28)
2022-06-19T15:49:41.913966+00:00 app[web.1]: at Socket._onTimeout (node:net:516:8)
2022-06-19T15:49:41.913967+00:00 app[web.1]: at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:559:17)
2022-06-19T15:49:41.913967+00:00 app[web.1]: at processTimers (node:internal/timers:502:7)]
2022-06-19T15:49:41.913967+00:00 app[web.1]: at Pool.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:336:35)
2022-06-19T15:49:41.913968+00:00 app[web.1]: at Pool.emit (node:events:527:28)
2022-06-19T15:49:41.913968+00:00 app[web.1]: at Connection.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:280:12)
2022-06-19T15:49:41.913969+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:642:26)
2022-06-19T15:49:41.913969+00:00 app[web.1]: at Connection.emit (node:events:527:28)
2022-06-19T15:49:41.913969+00:00 app[web.1]: at Socket.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:199:10)
2022-06-19T15:49:41.913969+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:641:28)
2022-06-19T15:49:41.913970+00:00 app[web.1]: at Socket.emit (node:events:527:28)
2022-06-19T15:49:41.913970+00:00 app[web.1]: at Socket._onTimeout (node:net:516:8)
2022-06-19T15:49:41.913970+00:00 app[web.1]: at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:559:17)
2022-06-19T15:49:41.913971+00:00 app[web.1]: at processTimers (node:internal/timers:502:7)
2022-06-19T15:49:41.913971+00:00 app[web.1]: Emitted 'error' event on NativeConnection instance at:
2022-06-19T15:49:41.913972+00:00 app[web.1]: at Immediate.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:325:19)
2022-06-19T15:49:41.913972+00:00 app[web.1]: at processImmediate (node:internal/timers:466:21)
2022-06-19T15:49:42.070420+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2022-06-19T15:49:42.125739+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2022-06-19T16:17:23.562964+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2022-06-19T16:17:25.609672+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2022-06-19T16:17:27.383132+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2022-06-19T16:17:27.383148+00:00 app[web.1]: > v2@1.0.0 start
2022-06-19T16:17:27.383148+00:00 app[web.1]: > node app.js
2022-06-19T16:17:27.383149+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2022-06-19T16:17:27.708851+00:00 app[web.1]: Warning: connect.session() MemoryStore is not
2022-06-19T16:17:27.708872+00:00 app[web.1]: designed for a production environment, as it will leak
2022-06-19T16:17:27.708872+00:00 app[web.1]: memory, and will not scale past a single process.
2022-06-19T16:17:27.712065+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:22) DeprecationWarning: `open()` is deprecated in mongoose >= 4.11.0, use `openUri()` instead, or set the `useMongoClient` option if using `connect()` or `createConnection()`. See http://mongoosejs.com/docs/4.x/docs/connections.html#use-mongo-client
2022-06-19T16:17:27.712066+00:00 app[web.1]: (Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
2022-06-19T16:17:27.712749+00:00 app[web.1]: Yelp camp is running
2022-06-19T16:17:27.886482+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2022-06-19T16:17:57.722817+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2022-06-19T16:17:57.722845+00:00 app[web.1]: node:events:505
2022-06-19T16:17:57.722847+00:00 app[web.1]: throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
2022-06-19T16:17:57.722847+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2022-06-19T16:17:57.723521+00:00 app[web.1]: Error [MongoError]: failed to connect to server [ds249605.mlab.com:49605] on first connect [Error [MongoError]: connection 0 to ds249605.mlab.com:49605 timed out
2022-06-19T16:17:57.723522+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.MongoError.create (/app/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/error.js:29:11)
2022-06-19T16:17:57.723522+00:00 app[web.1]: at Socket.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:200:20)
2022-06-19T16:17:57.723523+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:641:28)
2022-06-19T16:17:57.723523+00:00 app[web.1]: at Socket.emit (node:events:527:28)
2022-06-19T16:17:57.723523+00:00 app[web.1]: at Socket._onTimeout (node:net:516:8)
2022-06-19T16:17:57.723524+00:00 app[web.1]: at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:559:17)
2022-06-19T16:17:57.723524+00:00 app[web.1]: at processTimers (node:internal/timers:502:7)]
2022-06-19T16:17:57.723524+00:00 app[web.1]: at Pool.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:336:35)
2022-06-19T16:17:57.723524+00:00 app[web.1]: at Pool.emit (node:events:527:28)
2022-06-19T16:17:57.723525+00:00 app[web.1]: at Connection.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:280:12)
2022-06-19T16:17:57.723525+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:642:26)
2022-06-19T16:17:57.723526+00:00 app[web.1]: at Connection.emit (node:events:527:28)
2022-06-19T16:17:57.723526+00:00 app[web.1]: at Socket.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:199:10)
2022-06-19T16:17:57.723526+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:641:28)
2022-06-19T16:17:57.723526+00:00 app[web.1]: at Socket.emit (node:events:527:28)
2022-06-19T16:17:57.723527+00:00 app[web.1]: at Socket._onTimeout (node:net:516:8)
2022-06-19T16:17:57.723527+00:00 app[web.1]: at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:559:17)
2022-06-19T16:17:57.723527+00:00 app[web.1]: at processTimers (node:internal/timers:502:7)
2022-06-19T16:17:57.723527+00:00 app[web.1]: Emitted 'error' event on NativeConnection instance at:
2022-06-19T16:17:57.723527+00:00 app[web.1]: at Immediate.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:325:19)
2022-06-19T16:17:57.723528+00:00 app[web.1]: at processImmediate (node:internal/timers:466:21)
2022-06-19T16:17:57.853658+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2022-06-19T16:17:57.901912+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2022-06-19T16:25:13.075251+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=damp-hollows-70339.herokuapp.com request_id=c987ba77-316b-4cbf-a5e0-e92dcbbc615f fwd="73.225.207.205" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-06-19T16:25:13.364126+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=damp-hollows-70339.herokuapp.com request_id=288df5bc-ed7d-41e5-a498-41f99e03b854 fwd="73.225.207.205" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Comment: You could serve the app locally and debug from there vs. relying on the logs of the deployed app. I think there is an add on called papertrail that allows more detailed logs btw

Comment: Those logs don't tell us much, but they also don't look right. There are lots of extraneous spaces. Did you manipulate them somehow before pasting here? Please [edit] the relevant code into your question.

Comment: Just ran 'heroku logs' in the command line, and updated the post with that information. I added it through a javascript snippet as stackoverflow was telling me it was improperly formatted when trying to do add it otherwise.